# check if email already exists in firebase in flutter application and display error text on screen

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm currently developing a flutter app that requires users to register before using it. I use Firebase Authentication and would like to check whether an email is already registered in the app.

currently I'm not able to fetch user email id.
I have to check it while registering in my app whether the email already in use or already existed in database and I have to display it on screen if it is already existed.
As of now, I am getting it displayed in my console and it has to be displayed on screen so as the user can check it.

can anyone help me out.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From firebase flutter Document [Link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#emailpassword-registration--sign-in)

```
try {
  UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "barry.allen@example.com",
    password: "SuperSecretPassword!"
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
    print('The password provided is too weak.');
//This code below is what your looking for
  } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    print('The account already exists for that email.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

Then you can do something like this

```
else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    this.error = 'The account already exists for that email.'
    setState((){})
  }
```